# Passing parameters in a function inside another function?

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

I m searching for some help

It is possible to set a function with Arguments/Parameters inside another function in php? Here i have a theoretical example.

```
<?php

// Function with parameter/s
function funcOne($arg) {
    return $arg;
}

// Parameter/s inside another function.. Possible!?
function funcTwo() {
    return funcOne($arg);
}
```

When i try to set the parameter like this

```
funcOne('Alex');
echo funcTwo();
```

I get the following notice error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: arg in...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You just need to call the second function, but the function also needs to get the parameter to call the first function with it.

Comment: funcTwo() does not know about $arg, it is not in it's variable scope, not visible to is.

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 for your answer. That solve my doubt. :)

Comment: Gave you a detailed answer for your understanding. Use object oriented concept. Follow more about the scope of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Function with parameter/s
function funcOne($arg) {
    return $arg;
}

// Parameter/s inside another function.. Possible!?
function funcTwo() {
    return funcOne($arg);
}

funcOne('Alex');
//Call is made to function one which returned an ARG.
```

**NOTE that here the function just returned the arg and forgot about it, now that argument is NO WHERE stored to be used**

```
//Now here inside the functionTwo scope $arg is never defined.
echo funcTwo();
```

**You may do the following using classes and objects**

```
class MyClass {

    public $classarg;

    public function funcOne($arg) {
        $this->classarg = $arg; //assigned the argument to a class variable
    }

    function funcTwo() {
        return $this->classarg; //using the class variable to test
    }

}

$myobj = new MyClass();
$myobj->funcOne('Alex');
echo $myobj->funcTwo()
```

> You can also use global variable to achieve what you want, but I will NOT recommend to use it as Object Oriented Programming is what we should be using going forward

Comment: Thanks @Dharam for the great explanation. I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

`funcOne('Alex')`is not setting a parameter, it is calling the function funcOne().
When `funcOne($arg)` executes, it returns the parameter $arg to the caller.
`echo funcOne('Alex')` will echo `Alex`, because that is the value returned.
After return, funcOne does not know about 'Alex' any more.

when you call `funcTwo()`, it executes `funcOne($arg)`, but `$arg` is not defined: it has no value assigned.

Comment: Thanks @PaulH for this tip :)

Comment: Sorry, i dont have sufficient reputation to do that!

Answer (score -1):

```
function funcTwo($arg) {
    return funcOne($arg);
}
```

Note that you should learn to use variables before making functions.

Comment: Thanks Julie for your help. Yep, i will :)